# Apache 2.2 Change HTTP Request Method From POST to GET

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Is there a way I can change the HTTP Request Method from POST to GET using apache modules such as mod_rewrite or 3rd party module ?

The reason I'm doing this is to minimize server side changes as I'm doing this for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually read POST data in rewrite mod, as the values are in the body rather than in the headers. In my opinion, you might as well do it in your application server. Just create a url that does a redirect from POST to GET, and have apache run as a reverse proxy on this url.

Hope that helps.